# What should our "elevator pitch" be?

Tags: discussion

From http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/ :

```
Imagine you’ve just gotten on an elevator with a friendly stranger. You have precisely one floor to describe your community to them. What would you say? The elevator pitch is a brief sentence that describes what your site is about. Every word counts!

Once decided, it can be sliced and diced to form:

the tagline
the motto
the blurb under the logo
a convenience redirect “nickname” for the site
perhaps eventually the domain name in some form
(Due to a variety of practical difficulties with domain names, we prefer to de-emphasize domain name selection. Most sites will retain their topic.stackexchange.com names indefinitely.)

Naming is hard — really hard. But if you can come up with a sensible elevator pitch for your community, it’s a great starting point.
```

This is a very important topic, but only parts of it have been discussed to this point.

Ideas? Be sure to address as many of the above points as you can.

Comment: @Skippy only parts of this have been discussed up to this point. Although that question covers some of the information, it does not cover it all.

Comment: The other question was intended to cover the essential 7 beta Q, so I think it's better to mark this as dup, it will be a good signpost and edit the other Q accordingly, or it's splitting the discussion